# Changing button label on click with grommet?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, grommet

Does anyone have any insight into changing button label on click when using grommet UI and styled components? Is it easier to just use a custom button rather than grommets?

Comment: Share you code,

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples on how to make the Button label change onClick action:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { grommet, Box, Button, Grommet, Text } from "grommet";

const App = () => {
  const [label, setLabel] = useState(1);
  const [name, setName] = useState("shimi");

  const flipName = name => {
    return name === "shimi" ? setName("shai") : setName("shimi");
  };

  return (
    <Grommet theme={grommet}>
      <Box pad="small" gap="small" width="small">
        // label is a number that is being increased on every click event
        <Button
          label={label}
          onClick={() => {
            setLabel(label + 1);
          }}
        />
        // label string is controlled with external logic outside of the button.
        <Button
          label={<Text weight="400">{name}</Text>}
          onClick={() => {
            flipName(name);
          }}
        />
      </Box>
    </Grommet>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In addition to the examples above, in Grommet, you don't have to use the `label` prop and you can leverage the Button children to control the way your Button display.